# Can you read a USB flash drive from an Android phone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, usb, usb-host-mode

I have a Samsung Galaxy S (i9000) with Android 2.1.

I am wondering if it can read a USB flash drive. It will be really useful to copy files across USB drives so you don't have to carry laptops around.

I think if there is a cable/converter to plugin a USB into the phone and there is an app to read the connected USB drive, I don't see why it can't be done.

The problem is do the cable and app exist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes and Kinda.

You're talking about [USB On the Go (OTG)](http://www.usb.org/developers/onthego/) and Android is capable of it but it's not officially supported.  I couldn't find any apps in the app market that handle it but here are a couple people that got it working:

http://sven.killig.de/android/N1/2.2/usb_host/ *(this guy basically turned his Nexus One into a whole work station)*

http://www.tombom.co.uk/blog/?p=124

That second tutorial tells you to hack a cable but you can actually buy an OTG cable so this isn't necessary.

Also, I've seen some phones claim they are going to come out with USB OTG a while ago but I don't recall anything ever materializing.

Comment: I see, it doesn't seem to be a very easy task. Thanks Matt!

Comment: Yes, too hard for me.  This really is a must have feature that I hope they come out with an easy solution for.

Answer (score 0):

The Samsung Galaxy S2 officially supports USB OTG. It seems it has a special adapter.